# Python: pushing sensor data from Raspberry Pi to xively

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2, xively

I have this project where I need to push GrovePi ultrasonic ranger data to xively but it keeps having error. I want the ultrasonic ranger to detect movement and count the number detected. This number will be push to xively.

This is the error I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just pushing any data to xively. From the error it looks like the code is having a problem pushing any data to xively, probably a wrong URL or API key.

For any further questions contact [us here](http://forum.dexterindustries.com) as it would be easier for us to help.